# Can't get Google maps API when HTML loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps

I am trying to run a Google maps API on my Contact page for the site from a **Blix mobile template**, but I believe that since the Contact page is loaded over the main page or due to the custom scripts that have the source for the MAP API does not get called at all.
I know that the code I want to run is not a problem, but my script does not end up called at all in my template, and I have no idea what to try since I'm a beginner.

You can find [here](https://alecu-1be30.web.app/) the site itself. The problem I have is the contact page.

```css
        #map{
            height: 80%;
            width: 80%;
        }
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
        }
```

```html
        <div id="map">
<script>
            console.log("test 1");
          var map;
          function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'),
        
              {center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 20), zoom: 16});
              console.log("test 2");
        
          var iconBase =
              'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/';
              console.log("test 3");
        
          var icons = {
            info: {
              icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
            }
          };
              console.log("test 4");
        
          var features = [
            {
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 20),
              type: 'info'
            }
          ];
              console.log("test 5");
        
          // Create markers.
          for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: features[i].position,
              icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
              map: map
            });
          };
            console.log("test 6");
        }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCg9sodxDOjqPW1H5Xkmqu1ed1TPDVt1E0&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the Maps Script before the actual JS and then call the function at the end of the bottom in JS, so please use:

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCg9sodxDOjqPW1H5Xkmqu1ed1TPDVt1E0"></script>

<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'),

      {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 20),
        zoom: 16
      });

    var iconBase =
      'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/';

    var icons = {
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
      }
    };

    var features = [{
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 20),
      type: 'info'
    }];

    // Create markers.
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: features[i].position,
        icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
        map: map
      });
    };
  }

  initMap();
</script>
```

Comment: It works here. You can simply click the "Run code snippet" button and the Map working.

Comment: I've analyzed your contact page and saw that you didn't include the source snippets at all. The div with map is missing as well as the whole JS script for maps. The only thing you included is the CSS.

Comment: They are placed. Use inspect element on the blank area in the contact page, below the blue button.

Comment: Well, when I use inspect, I can see them as well, however, when you look through the source code (Ctrl + U in Chrome) then you can see it. That means you inserted these snippets not in the html file but an another JS file injects it. Is this right? Just to stick with your answer.

Comment: Yes, what it shows on the view source is the main page to the contents of the contact page are inserted over.

Comment: Then it becomes a bit more complicated. Is there an opportunity to paste the code snippets directly into the Contact HTML file?
Otherwise, I have to look it up in detail when I'm back home again.

Comment: Apparently there is a function where I can place all my scripts but I do not know how or where to add the source for the google map API in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have added map div at bottom of the HTML body. Add `<div id="map">` inside of Contact page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete HTML File:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <style>
    #map {
      height: 80%;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCg9sodxDOjqPW1H5Xkmqu1ed1TPDVt1E0"></script>

  <script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'),

        {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 20),
          zoom: 16
        });

      var iconBase = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/';

      var icons = {
        info: {
          icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
        }
      };

      var features = [{
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 20),
        type: 'info'
      }];

      // Create markers.
      for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: features[i].position,
          icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
          map: map
        });
      };
    }

    initMap();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```